# Сортивка массива, используя итераторы

Tags: сортировка, итераторы, c++

Здравствуйте.
Относительно недавно мне помогли разобраться с итераторами, точнее понять их реализацию и т.п. (за что спасибо тем, кто помогал). Вот создам ещё один вопрос (ибо тот именно свою задачу исчерпал).

Дело вот в чем... Прописал я эти итераторы, вроде бы понял как что к чему более менее..
Получился следующий класс:

```
class Array
    {
    private:
        int n;
        int* arr;

    public:
        class Iterator
        {
        public:
            int *p;
            Iterator()
            {
                p = nullptr;
            }
            Iterator(int *pv)
            {
                p = pv;
            }
            int operator*() const
            {
                return *p;
            }
            /*Iterator operator++(int)
            {
                int* temp = p;
                return ++temp;
            }*/
            Iterator& operator++()
            {
                ++p;
                return *this;
            }
            Iterator operator++(int)
            {
                return Iterator(p++);
            }
            Iterator& operator--()
            {
                --p;
                return *this;
            }
            Iterator operator--(int)
            {
                return Iterator(p--);
            }
            const int& operator[](const std::size_t&pv)
            {
                return p[pv];
            }
            Iterator& operator+=(const std::size_t&pv)
            {
                p += pv; return *this;
            }
            int* base() const
            {
                return p;
            }
            Iterator operator=(const int a)
            {
                *p = a; return *this;
            }
        };
        Iterator begin()
        {
            return Iterator(arr);
        }
        Iterator end()
        {
            return arr+n;
        }
        friend inline bool operator==(const Iterator&it1, const Iterator&it2)
        {
            return it1.base() == it2.base();
        }
        friend inline bool operator!=(const Iterator&it1, const Iterator&it2)
        {
            return it1.base() != it2.base();
        }
        friend inline bool operator <(const Iterator&it1, const Iterator&it2)
        {
            return it1.base() < it2.base();
        }
        friend inline bool operator >(const Iterator&it1, const Iterator&it2)
        {
            return it1.base() > it2.base();
        }
        friend inline bool operator <=(const Iterator&it1, const Iterator&it2)
        {
            return it1.base() <= it2.base();
        }
        friend inline bool operator >=(const Iterator&it1, const Iterator&it2)
        {
            return it1.base() >= it2.base();
        }
        friend Iterator operator+(const Iterator&it, std::size_t n)
        {
            return Array::Iterator(it.base() + n);
        }
        friend Iterator operator-(const Iterator&it, std::size_t n)
        {
            return Array::Iterator(it.base() - n);
        }
...
}
```

Всё вроде отлично... Но теперь я попытался переделать алгоритмы сортировки под эти итераторы. Ну.. Возьмем к примеру самый простой InsertionSort:
Без итераторов было так:

```
void Array::InsertionSort() 
{
       int i, j, key;       
       for (i = 1; i < length; i++)     
       {
             key = arr[i];
             j = i - 1;
             while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key)
             {
                   arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; 
                   j--; 
             }
             arr[j + 1] = key;  
       }
 }
```

После того, как я приделал итераторы получилось так:

```
void Array::InsertionSort() 
{
       int key; 
       Iterator start = Array::begin();
       Iterator end = Array::end();
       Iterator temp;
       for (++start; start != end; start++)     
       {
             key = *start;              
             temp = start - 1;
             while (temp >= Array::begin() && *temp > key)
             {
                 (temp+1) = *temp;
                 --temp;
             }
             compares++;
             (temp+1) = key;
       }
 }
```

Концепцию правильно понял, или не очень?
Можно ли как-то это оптимизировать?

И ещё... Я хотел для сравнения элемента и сменой их мест, чтобы было что-то типо такого

```
*it1 = *it2;
```

Такая запись не получалась, поэтому я через час попыток остановился на такой перегрузке:

```
Iterator operator=(const int a)
            {
                *p = a; return *this;
            }
```

Быть может есть более оптимальный вариант? И можно ли перегрузить так, как хотел я?
(`*it1 = *it2`);

И как быть алгоритмам сортировки таким, как шейкерная или быстрая...
Та же вообще границы ... И нужно брать по индексу.. Как итераторы в таком случае использовать? - Может быть с помощью перегруженных [] или есть оптимальнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы понять, что и как "правильно" с итераторами, проще всего проводить аналогию с указателями. Указатель можно разыменовать? Можно.

```
int* p;
*p = 4; // присваивание ОК
int x = *p; // чтение ОК

const int* p;
*p = 4; // присваивание НЕЛЬЗЯ
int x = *p; // чтение ОК
```

То есть, объект итератора по поведению должен быть вообще неотличим от обычного указателя.

И значит вам надо два оператора доступа к значению:

```
// этот оператор будет разрешать только чтение для константных итераторов
// и, в случае, int как вы и сделали его можно заменить на
// int operator*() const
// без потери качества
const int& operator*() const
{
    return *p;
}
// этот оператор будет разрешать и чтение и запись для неконстантных итераторов
int& operator*()
{
    return *p;
}
```

И тогда конструкция вида

```
Iterator it1;
Iterator it2;
*it1 = *it2;
```

будет работать, потому что итераторы не константные.

Вот так тоже будет работать:

```
Iterator it1;
const Iterator it2;
*it1 = *it2;
```

А вот так уже не будет:

```
const Iterator it1;
const Iterator it2;
*it1 = *it2;
```

И если вы замените в данном случае итераторы на обычные указатели, ничего не поменяется.

Что касается, как использовать итераторы в реализации алгоритмов: представьте, что вместо итераторов у вас указатели и напишите алгоритм с их помощью. Потом поменяйте все на итераторы и, если итераторы сконструированы правильно, все должно продолжать работать.

Answer (score 1):

> *it1 = *it2;

Не получится. Потому что слева, за оператором присваивания должно стоять lvalue. Т.е. нечто, что обладает адресом в памяти. А *p есть значение, а не объект. Поэтому так не получится.
С другой стороны, никто не мешает написать функцию swap(it1, it2). И пользоваться ей. Не нужно зацикливаться на перегрузке операторов.
И я бы попробовал перегрузить оператор = для самих итераторов. Тогда будет порядок.

```
// как-то так, но я не уверен на 100%.
Iterator & operator =(Iterator /*const*/ & S) // const нас не устраивает
{
    int *tmp = p;
    if (&S != this)
    {
      p = S.p;
      S.p = tmp;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Теперь мы можем написать

```
it1 = it2; // поменять местами.
```

Другой вопрос, что при этом другой функционал поломается.

Comment: @Другой вопрос, что при этом другой функционал поломается.@
Согласен... Просто запись it1 = it2 мне тоже нужно использовать, она присваивает указатели...
А я просто думал, что быть может можно какую-то операцию поменять\перегрузить, чтобы было именно \*it1 = \*it2...

"Не получится. Потому что слева, за оператором присваивания должно стоять lvalue. Т.е. нечто, что обладает адресом в памяти. А *p есть значение, а не объект."
Всмысле?
Немножечко не понял...
Мы ведь можем сделать такую запись:
int\* value;
\*value = 5;

Comment: М-м-м. Да, верно, \*value = 5 в случае если value - указатель можно написать. Просто как я понимаю проблема в том, что у Вас написано <pre>int operator*() const</pre>
Т.е. у Вас получается так: <pre>int f(Iterator &);
f(it1) = f(it2);</pre>

Comment: О! Кажется нашел способ. Нужно замутить что-то в духе:
<pre>typedef int\* PINT;
PINT& func (PINT& p)
{return p;}
// теперь мы можем сделать так:
int \*a,  \*b;
func(a)=func(b); // присвоить a значение b</pre>

Comment: Эх... Ну это не совсем то, однако спасибо за совет)

А ещё.. Насчёт оптимизации... Оптимально ли у меня это реализовано?

В сортировках типа шейкерной, мне указатели, которые меняются присваивать нужно будет что-то вроде Iterator left = Array::begin();
right += l-1; что-то вроде того?

Answer (score 1):

Если в дополнение к этому методу:

```
int operator*() const
{
    return *p;
}
```

добавить неконстантный:

```
int& operator*()
{
    return *p;
}
```

то разыменованному итератору вполне можно будет присваивать новое значение.